# Correct use of super() to .pop() off names from a list in a parent class for each child instance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I'm building a game in which I've made a `ComputerPlayer()` class that is a child of a `Players()` class. I'm using a list of names in the `Players()` class for the constructor in the child class to randomly grab a name for each computer player each time it is instantiated, and `pop()` it off so names can't be assigned twice. The bit of code looks like this:

```
class Players(object):

    names = ['Carl', 'James', 'Bob', 'Jamal', 'Kris', 'Andy', 'Rupert', 'Gerald', 'Pat',
             'Gloria', 'Hannah', 'Priscilla', 'Sarah', 'Silvia']

class ComputerPlayer(Players):

    def ___init___(self):
        self.name = super(ComputerPlayer, self).names.pop(randint(0, len(super(ComputerPlayer, self).names) - 1))
```

So what I want to do is instantiate a new `ComputerPlayer()` object for each computerized player in a `Game()` class, which if I always want the same amount of players I could do pretty easily with:

```
class Game(object):

    def ___init___(self):
        self.player1 = ComputerPlayer()
        self.player2 = ComputerPlayer()
        self.player3 = ComputerPlayer()
```

Or if I want the human player to be able to select how many computer opponents they'd like to play against, I could pass an argument to `Game()` and do:

```
def __init___(self, num):
    self.players = []
    for x in range(0,num):
        self.players.append(ComputerPlayer())
```

When I first started this question I wanted to know if there was a way to access each instance of `ComputerPlayer()` with a reference to it's randomly assigned name, but as I wrote I realized that there would be no real benefit to doing that and it would probably make things needlessly complicated; the names are really just to display to the human player to make the game feel more 'human'.

However, although I know I'm using `super()` *correctly* in the `ComputerPlayer()` class, would it necessarily be the *preferred* way of doing it? Using a direct reference to `Players().names` works just as well, and it would shorten that ugly line of code quite a bit.

The `Game()` class will have the main methods to control logic for the game, so is it the correct class to create my individual computer players?

Any other comments, questions, or suggestions would be appreciated. The game will be "Street Craps" btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you make it sound like the names are just used for the computer player.
in that case why not put it within the ComputerPlayer class and skip using super?

also if you create more than len(name) number of computer players, your code is going to error

Comment: if you are worried about a human player's name duplicating a computer players name, then it does make sense to have everything in the parent (Player) class. but then note that you will have to check to make sure you are not popping/drawing a human's name when initializing a computer player

Comment: Yes, the names are only used for the computer players, the human player will be asked to enter their own name. Thanks for pointing that out! I will also have to limit the number of players to len(name), I didn't think of that.